# Appium is get an error "unable to create new remote session"

Tags: android, appium

I'm Working in appium.  previously,  my code doesn't work in above 5.o
When I changed its working fine.  android version.   `driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.2:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);`   above code works fine in above 5.0 android version. And the app was launch and couldn't open the app and still got the same error.

Android setup

```java
public class AndroidSetup {

    protected AndroidDriver driver;

    protected void prepareAndroidForAppium() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.6.3");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Mi Phone");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "/home/naveen/IdeaProjects/QberLoginPage/app/Qber_Customer_V1.6.0.apk");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.ionicframework");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.2:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }
}
```

Logintest

```java
public class Logintest extends AndroidSetup {
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        prepareAndroidForAppium();
    }
    
    @AfterClass   
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void login() {
        new Login(driver).invalidLogin();
    }
}
```

loginpage

```java
public class Login extends BasePage {

    public Login(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    public Login invalidLogin() {
        return new Login(driver);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Mar 21, 2017 2:02:10 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Mar 21, 2017 2:02:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
Mar 21, 2017 2:02:52 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
    org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{app=/home/naveen/IdeaProjects/QberLoginPage/app/Qber_Customer_V1.6.0.apk, appPackage=com.ionicframework.qber653346, appActivity=Main Activity, appium-version=1.6.3, platformVersion=6.0, platformName=Android, deviceName=Mi Phone}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
    Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
    System info: host: 'naveen-Inspiron-3542', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-66-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
    Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
```

Comment: After fail 1000 times and 3 weeks of time finally I made it, it is all happen run jenkins and appium server in local machine.
Thanks a ton

Comment: hello guys I am facing the same kind of issue , I am unable to create the session with my real device my Appium server starts but after some time it freezes and it throws an exception org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\sign.jar" C:\Software\selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk --override"
java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty Environment 1) eclipse 2) appium 1.4.16.1
3) window 7
4) seleni

Comment: I am also facing the same issue org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'farms.io.farmsiofo' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: 'farms.io.activity.StartActivity' or 'farms.io.farmsiofo.farms.io.activity.StartActivity' never started. Visit https://github.com/appium/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like session between client and server is failing to get initiated. I noticed that URL you use for Appium server is `"http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"`. This could be an issue, since as I understood you are running Appium on the same machine where your client scripts reside, try using `"http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"` instead. Or use your local host ip address `"http://127.0.1.1:4723/wd/hub"`.

In general make sure that your Appium server is started and running. You can do this by visiting URL in browser `localhost:4723/wd/hub/status`. You will be able to connect to URL and see something like this:`{"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.5.3","revision":null}},"sessionId":null}`

PS. It strange though if you are able to initiate session with the same settings for KitKat devices. I would expect it to fail for all devices since it couldn't pass desired capabilities to server to initiate automation session.

Comment: THis question is resolved because appActivity name there is a space between the words.